# Magento 2 Migration. Ignore product attribute set

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, data-migration

I'm running a data migration using the data migration tool provided by magento.

When running I get:

```
 [ERROR]: Incompatibility in data. Source document: eav_attribute_group. Field: attribute_group_name. Error: The product attribute set "Default" does not contain all required attribute group names "General, Prices, Design, Images"
```

I wish to mention that the table `eav_attribute_group` is ignored in my `map.xml`. And `map.xml` is correctly referened in my `config.xml`

If the given document is ignored why am I getting an Error regarding it?
Other from map.xml are successfully ignored.

Any pointers on how to fix this? Can I entirely ignore a product attribute set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically what was going on here was this.

I had some attribute sets on M1 that did not have certain attribute groups.

I added them and did not receive this error anymore.

Comment: Can you plz explain more in deep with e.g as i am facing same issue? Thanks

Comment: Each attribute set must have certain attribute groups. e.g General